# Survey adding text options for all values of a rating scale

Tags: 2010, survey-list

When creating a survey you can create a rating scale. Be default you can set the following.

1. Strongly Disagree
2. 
3. Neither Agree nor Disagree
4. 
5. Strongly Agree

Is it possible to set the two  options?

1. Strongly Disagree
2. Disagree
3. Neither Agree nor Disagree
4. Agree
5. Strongly Agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on the rating scale, you could simply create a multiple choice question with the ratings you desire to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use client JavaScript code to dynamically update the UI within the page.

Use SharePoint Designer to update the NewForm-, DispForm-, EditForm- and Summary-ASPX-pages with custom JavaScript code.

Add the following code within the content tag with `contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain"`.

Code for NewForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++)
{
    if (tables[i].summary == 'Rating Scale Question')
    {
        var trs = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
        var tds = trs[0].getElementsByTagName('td'); 
        tds[2].colSpan = 1;
        tds[2].innerHTML = 'your range text';
        tds[3].colSpan = 1;
        tds[3].innerHTML = your range text';
        tds[4].colSpan = 1;
        tds[4].innerHTML = your range text';
        tds[5].colSpan = 1;
        tds[5].innerHTML = your range text'; 
    }
}
</script>
```

Code for Summary.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++)
{
    if (tables[i].className == 'ms-surveyVBarT')
    {
        tables[i].deleteRow(0);
        var row = tables[i].insertRow(0);
        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell0.innerHTML = your range text';
        cell1.innerHTML = your range text';
        cell2.innerHTML = your range text';
        cell3.innerHTML = your range text';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom rating scale can be easier do using SP Designer.
We can make custom new page using SP Designer and add some javascript.

Here is the link for visual tutorial in SharePoint 2013 and SP Designer 2013 :
[Add Custom Rating Scale Text in Sharepoint Survey](http://menetes.blogspot.co.id/2016/03/add-custom-rating-scale-text-in.html)

Answer (score -1):

Nice Article on SharePoint Survey Lists

Sudheer
Create Survey Lists in SharePoint : http://sharepointsolutions-sudheer.blogspot.in/2014/11/creating-survey-list-programmatically.html

Comment: Linking to your own blog isn't what we do here. Please add more explaination in this post, or it may be deleted!